# The Sims Mobile: can't restore progress on different device

Tags: ios, games

I've got a Sims Mobile game in progress on an iPhone that's using game center (I can see the game center user name flash by as the game loads.)  [In theory](https://help.ea.com/en/help/the-sims/the-sims-mobile/save-your-game-progress-in-the-sims-mobile/), I should be able to log into game center on a different device (another iPhone) install the same app and it should prompt me to load previously saved progress.

When I tried this, I'm logged in with the same game center account on the second phone, and I can see Sims Mobile on the second phone knows that game center is active, but it never prompts me to reload previous progress.  Googling around it looks like, it doesn't prompt you until after the intro tutorial is done, but I still don't get prompted even after the tutorial.

Back on the original device, I can see that the game progress is where I left off, so I think the game *is* intact somewhere, just not getting loaded on the second device.

Can anybody give me a hand?  I have a feeling I'm missing a step somewhere, but the process seems like it should be pretty straightforward.